# Prove: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \frac{x_{n-k+1}}{X_{i}} > \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x_{k}}{X_{i}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $n$ and $k$ two natural numbers such that $ k < \frac{n}{2}$ and $n$ real numbers such that $x_{1} > x_2 > \ldots > x_{n} > 0$

I'm not 100% sure whether this inequality always holds. However, I conducted a simulation by generating $n$ numbers uniformly between $0.01$ and $1$ for different values of $k$, and it seems to be valid.

I would like to prove that:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \frac{x_{n-k+1}}{X_{i}} > \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x_{k}}{X_{i}}$ where $X_{i} = \sum_{j=i}^{n} x_{j}$, in other terms show that:

$\frac{x_{n-k+1}}{x_{1} + \ldots + x_{n}} + \ldots + \frac{x_{n-k+1}}{x_{n-k+1} + \ldots + x_{n}}$ $>$ $\frac{x_{k}}{x_{1} + \ldots + x_{n}} + \ldots + \frac{x_{k}}{x_{k} + \ldots + x_{n}}$

For example, if $k=1$, the inequality becomes trivial since:

$\frac{x_{n}}{x_{1} + \ldots + x_{n}} + \ldots + \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n}} > 1 > \frac{x_{1}}{x_{1} + \ldots + x_{n}}$

You can impose harsher conditions while conducting the proof, such as finding a smaller bound for k

Comment: I changed $k$ to be strictly smaller than $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Did you check $n = 5, k = 2$?

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example with $n=5$ and $k=2$: $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0.9$, $x_3=0.09$, $x_4 = 0.009$, $x_5 = 0.001$, then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{x_4}{X_i}=1.0035<\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{x_2}{X_i}=1.35. $$
The overall magnitude of both sums is controlled by the common numerator, so if $x_{n-k+1}$ is much smaller than $x_k$, there is no guarantee that the inequality will hold.

Comment: You are right,  what do you think about the case when we add the hypothesis that $x_{n} > 1$ ? I tried to add $1$ to all the elements you provided, and the inequality holds by getting  $1.17$ for the left sum against $0.65$ for the right one

Comment: I don't think it works. You could just multiply all the numbers in my example by 1001 so they are all larger than 1, but this does not change the values of both sums.

Comment: Yeah right, so this seems to be false, however the simulation seems to always work, so I'm wondering what kind of additional hypthesis we can add to make it work

Comment: If my choice of numbers above belongs to the sample space of your simulation, then your simulation cannot `always' work. There must be a non-zero probability (albeit it could be small) that the inequality is violated. For example, if you don't get a violation in 1000 simulated paths, how about $10^8$ simulated paths?